# I need help to design a circuit to suppress amp peaks

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, circuit-protection

First: im new here and this is my first question so if you think that I should ask or behave in a different way, feel free to tell me.

The (My) Problem:
We run LEDs on a test stand with ~5V,2.3A
and have the Problem of brief (~20µs) disconnects between the LED and the power supply.
The disconnect is rapid, so that in some cases the supply will not shut down. In case that happens the voltage at the open contacts increases and there is an amp Peak ~>5A at the Moment of reconnection which destroyes the LED.

I my idea for a circuit to solve that issue was this one:[image]

There should be a n-mos with a high power, low resistance Resistor in a series Connection in a parallel configation to the LED. The Gate Voltage should be taken of a voltage divider (someone mentioned to me that instead of R1 i should use a z-Diode, although they did not provide a reason for that) The increasing voltage should open the mosfet, wich creates a way to reduce the energy in the circuit and there is no peak when the LED is connected to the circuit again.

this one is similar, but there is an OP involved to drive the mosfet.
[image]

My aim is to simulate, build and test a prototype. It is not to create a PCB with the circuit yet. 
Since Im quite a newbie when it comes to simulations in LTSpice and desinging real circuits I have some difficulties to turn my ideas into a running solution.

eg.

-I know i need a resistor before the gate of mosfet, but which one?

-Or how to choose a fitting OP?

-Wich Mosfet shall i use here?

-What are the next steps ?

Thank you for reading, i hope to find help here.

Comment: Please avoid using potentially ambiguous terms terms like "open" or "closed" when referring to transistors. It's sometimes difficult to determine if you're using them like "open valve" or "open circuit" - which mean completely opposite things. "On" or "Off" would be less ambiguous.

Comment: What power supply are you using? LEDs should normally use constant current supplies which shouldn't behave like this.

Comment: Besides which, the current source in your diagrams is pointing the wrong way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean _suppress_, not _oppress_, but I still got your meaning.

Comment: Sounds like the LED driver is using current sense feedback. During the disconnect, there is zero current, so the control loop goes to max duty cycle and the output voltage spikes. Then upon re-connect, the high voltage stored in the output capacitor blows up the load.

Comment: This can potentially be fixed by adding a power Zener diode at the output of the power supply. Zener voltage must be higher than LED forward voltage. During the disconnect, when the output voltage starts to rise, the Zener will start to conduct, and allow the current output loop to remain in regulation. There are other ways to possibly deal with this. But we need full details. Schematics and/or datasheets of your LED driver and Vf/If details of the LED's themselves.

Comment: Why you disconnect between the LED and the power source? Is it possible to control the power supply or make a disconnect before the power supply?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent surges from intermittent impedance one must be able to detect impedance rise and shutdown output faster than the part can fail or not change the output voltage fast than it can detect an open conduction.

If you sense current and voltage then differentiate both to produce a protective reaction from either an open or a short, using some capacitance limits the voltage slew rate. BUT one must be aware this creates a line LC resonant condition which creates a different problem.

So slew rate must be managed in a control loop with a Bandwidth defined by your **specs**.

To systematically find an acceptable solution, one must 1st define measurable acceptance criteria or **specs** on surge current using Ohm's Law, energy stored with formulae like 1/2CV^2 and Safe Operating Current-time spec limit on your LEDs and drivers.

So always start a design problem with **Specs** rather than solutions that may become poor band-aids.  Such as dV/dt, dI/dt limit, soft-start spec, momentary interupt dV/dt limit.

The essential part of all of this is the current sense Resistor which are typically choosing for 100mV drop max or << 0.25 W . But also remember if you shut off the current at too fast a slew rate the back EMF = V=LdI/dt from cable inductance.

The critical part of learning is how to master these concepts and learn by examples that work if you can find any such circuits.  They may not be as simple as you would like.

This is why  CC power supplies are full of parts and not simply a CC regulator.  Power regulators often have OCP, OTP, UVP and step response times and overshoot to define these characteristics.

This requires some System Control Theory experience, how to read datasheets on every part, then put it all together into a proper Design Spec.

One commercial part for this is called a crowbar clamp or ..

> Bourns® LSP Series protectors are electronic shunts that provide a current bypass when an LED element in an LED string fails open circuit. This ensures the remaining string of LEDs will continue to function. There are many cases where high reliability of the LED lighting must be maintained, such as LCD backlighting, transport lighting, avionics, intrinsically safe and low maintenance lighting.

Then you design the trigger and shutdown to release the SCR’s holding current and restart after a suitable delay.

Comment: I didn't read thoroughly, but I think their problem is, in fact, coming from trace inductance. I'm glad to see you catch the point in what you wrote. +1

Comment: Often the surge current is I=dV/ESR from storage capacitance at over overvoltage but without negative  diode clamp protection that can certainly be an issue with long cables

Comment: I see some of you asking for the specs. Which Information should be given here?

Comment: pls define all input surges by V,I or Z, t and or J with acceptable output criteria or some universal std tests